# Using comparison test to tell whether the improper integral converge or diverge

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Determine whether the following integral converges or diverges
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}$
[image]
And assuming I have already proved the comparison tests, and right now I can use comparison test to prove the integral diverges

proof:$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}\ge \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{sin^2(x)}{sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{cos^2(x)}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}sec^2(x)=\left[tan(x)\right]_0^{\pi/2}=\infty$

for which clearly the original intergal diverges.

Is my proof correct? If it is wrong, where are the problems?

Comment: But My Teaching assistant in the class told me that I can not use comparison test becase "It simply doesn't work, you need to have function integrable on the interval (a,b) to start with, but in our case it is not bounded" and I have to split the integral. So who is correct?By the way, this is Introduction to Analysis II class

Comment: The comparison test you included in your post is correct and does not have such hypothesis (on the contrary in b: $f$ is supposed to be nonintegrable). Your proof is legit if you are supposed to know that statement as it is formulated there.

Comment: I have argued with TAs and he insisted that this proof is not right, I really do not do what to do that is why I asked here and more importantly I lost half of the points(lost 3 out of 6 points) on the exam because of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your proof is simple: from the statement itself, it is not guaranteed that $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}dx$$ is a well-defined object. You have to show the integration is well-defined first.

Of course, if you did the homework correctly, you would surely show that we can break down the interval into two, and thus on each interval there's only one singular point, so that the improper integral is defined according to our textbook definition. (By the way, you did not submit this homework). During the test, you can only use the statement so you have to repeat this step to use the comparison test.

After this class, you can surely do problems in your way, which is mathematically correct; in this test, however, I have to stick to the rubric. Eventually, you would find this tedious, but from my memory, your reasonings in exams are very sloppy. I definitely think the formal reasoning is a vital part of the course, and I hope you can practice a bit more on this in the future.

Comment: Yes, I did do the homework but I did not submit the homework because I do not have time to submit. And I do realize that splitting the integral to only keep it as one singularity is important, and it is also mentioned in the professor's lecture. Again, I do realize it is definitely my fault that I did not make it formal. And I will do try to practice more proof in the future as I will be taking a lot of proof classes in the future.

Comment: And one thing I complain about this class is how the lecture notes are written. In the lecture, the professor seems to use some "advanced" and "unusual" way to solve the problem, for example, just like first problem on the exam, for which we can surely use the L'hoptals rule but professor use the taylor expansion way to solve the problem,which is definitely not the standard. And this has created a lot of confusion as how original my proof needs to be and how rigorous the proof needs to be.

Comment: There are also other problems like seems like answer rubric does not want me to directly use some formula and taylor expansion while in the lecture notes, they explicitly use taylor series I am not allowed to use, which is the reason why I am frustrated about the answer key.